# binding xml to data repeater control

Tags: xml, datarepeater

i am having a xml file like this

```
<ward>  <pods>
<name>Pod A</name>
<direction>North</direction>
<beds>
  <id>a1</id>
  <id>a2</id>
  <id>a3</id>
  <id>a4</id>
  <id>a5</id>
</beds>   </pods>  <pods>
<name>Pod B</name>
<direction>North</direction>
<beds>
  <id>b1</id>
  <id>b2</id>
  <id>b3</id>
  <id>b4</id>
  <id>b5</id>
</beds>   </pods> </ward>
```

i am trying to put the names as column header and beds-> id as their children,
i am not at all having a clue to do this, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this and see what exactly you will have:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("Data.xml");
repeater.DataSource = dataSet;
repeater.DataBind();
```

If something displayed wrong - you can manually restructure it traversing `dataSet.Tables`
(I believe you can't change XML structure)

Comment: yes i think manipulating the dataset and table is the only way i belive. any way thanks sll.